# Windows 2012 IIS8 - Windows Authentication or Basic Authentication not available

Tags: authentication, iis, webdav

In the site manager for my WebDAV site some authentication types are missing.

There should also be a possibility for `Windows Authentication` and `Basic Authentication`.

[image]

How can I get the missing authentication types available?

Answer (score 2):

If certain authentication types are missing in the list you can add them through the `Add Roles and Features Wizard` or by using the `Turn windows features on or off` under Programs in the Control Panel.

In my windows 2012 server (IIS 8) the panel looks like this:

[image]

You can select the authentication roles you want to add from the list...

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this issue. run the below command in power shell and it will install IIS authentications.

> Install-WindowsFeature Web-Basic-Auth